# Is there a simple Scala 3 example of how to use `quoted.Type` as replacement for `TypeTag`?

Tags: scala, types, scala-macros, scala-3

[Martin Odersky said](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/scala-3-and-reflection/3627/7)

> Scala 3 has the quoted package, with `quoted.Expr` as a representation of expressions and `quoted.Type` as a representation of types. `quoted.Type` esentially replaces `TypeTag`. It does not have the same API but has similar functionality. It should be easier to use since it integrates well with quoted terms and pattern matching.

I knew how to use `TypeTag` in Scala 2:

```
def myFun[T](foo: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) =
  // and now I can do whatever I want with tag
```

but I have no idea how to do something similar with `Type`. I have a case where I need to keep around type information that was exactly the use case for `TypeTag`, but I can't find any examples of how to do this in Scala 3. (Well, people point to `izumi-reflect` and similar things, so I should say that I can't find any accessible--at least to me--examples.)

Can someone tell me (a) what's the type of the class that I should be using to store type info so that I can, for instance, use that info to correctly cast a value, and (b) how to use `quoted.Type` to get such a thing?

What I mean by (a) is that I have, say, an `Iterator[Stuff[?]]` with the equivalent of `case class Stuff[T](value: T, tag: TypeTag[T])`. When I get the next element from the iterator, I need to be able to cast it to a more specific type than `Stuff[?]`, and that's possible because the `tag` somehow reifies the type and avoids type erasure, in the same way that (explicitly) saving a `Class<T>` beside a value would in Java.

To really boil this down, what I want is to be able to write something like

```
def foo: Foo[T] = someFun(arg1: X, arg2: T)
```

and have the type information from `T` be pushed from the left side of the equality to the right, so that the information about what `T` was when `someFun` was called is accessible inside the body of `someFun`. I think the answer is "macros can do it", but heck if I can figure out how.

Comment: is that what you want ? https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty-macro-examples

Comment: This might give some ideas: https://github.com/gaeljw/typetrees (not sure it's up to date)

Comment: Dunno what's wrong with `izumi-reflect`. `def myFun[T : izumi.reflect.Tag](foo: T)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approach. It's too hard to expose actual `TypeRepr` outside macros (because of dependent types and implicit `Quotes`), so I'm creating own runtime `Type` hierarchy mirroring the one from `quotes.reflect.*`

```
case class TypeTag[T](tpe: my.Type)
object TypeTag:
  inline given [T]: TypeTag[T] = TypeTag(getType[T])

def typeTag[T: TypeTag]: TypeTag[T] = summon[TypeTag[T]]
def typeOf[T: TypeTag]: my.Type = summon[TypeTag[T]].tpe

object my:
  sealed trait Type
  case class ConstantType(constant: Constant) extends Type
  sealed trait NamedType extends Type:
    def qualifier: Type
    def name: String
  case class TermRef(qualifier: Type, name: String) extends NamedType
  case class TypeRef(qualifier: Type, name: String) extends NamedType //
  case class SuperType(thisTpe: Type, superTpe: Type) extends Type
  case class Refinement(parent: Type, name: String, info: Type) extends Type
  case class AppliedType(tycon: Type, args: List[Type]) extends Type
  case class AnnotatedType(underlying: Type, annot: Term) extends Type
  sealed trait AndOrType extends Type:
    def left: Type
    def right: Type
  case class AndType(left: Type, right: Type) extends AndOrType
  case class OrType(left: Type, right: Type) extends AndOrType
  case class MatchType(bound: Type, scrutinee: Type, cases: List[Type]) extends Type
  case class ByNameType(underlying: Type) extends Type
  case class ParamRef(binder: Type, paramNum: Int) extends Type //
  case class ThisType(tref: Type) extends Type //
  case class RecursiveThis(binder: RecursiveType) extends Type //
  case class RecursiveType(underlying: Type, recThis: RecursiveThis) extends Type //
  sealed trait LambdaType extends Type:
    def paramNames: List[String]
    def paramTypes: List[Type]
    def resType: Type
  sealed trait MethodOrPoly extends LambdaType
  case class MethodType(paramNames: List[String], paramTypes: List[Type], resType: Type) extends MethodOrPoly
  case class PolyType(paramNames: List[String], paramTypes: List[TypeBounds], resType: Type) extends MethodOrPoly
  case class TypeLambda(paramNames: List[String], paramTypes: List[TypeBounds], resType: Type) extends LambdaType
  case class MatchCase(pattern: Type, rhs: Type) extends Type
  case class TypeBounds(low: Type, hi: Type) extends Type
  case object NoPrefix extends Type

  sealed trait Term
  case class New(tpe: Type/*tpt: TypeTree*/) extends Term

  sealed trait Constant
  case class BooleanConstant(b: Boolean) extends Constant
  case class ByteConstant(b: Byte) extends Constant
  case class ShortConstant(s: Short) extends Constant
  case class IntConstant(i: Int) extends Constant
  case class LongConstant(l: Long) extends Constant
  case class FloatConstant(f: Float) extends Constant
  case class DoubleConstant(d: Double) extends Constant
  case class CharConstant(c: Char) extends Constant
  case class StringConstant(s: String) extends Constant
  case object UnitConstant extends Constant
  case object NullConstant extends Constant
  case class ClassOfConstant(tpe: Type) extends Constant

import scala.quoted.*

inline def getType[T]: my.Type = ${getTypeImpl[T]}

def getTypeImpl[T: Type](using Quotes): Expr[my.Type] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  def mkConstant(constant: Constant): Expr[my.Constant] = constant match
    case BooleanConstant(b) => '{my.BooleanConstant(${ Expr(b) })}
    case ByteConstant(b) => '{my.ByteConstant(${ Expr(b) })}
    case ShortConstant(s) => '{my.ShortConstant(${ Expr(s) })}
    case IntConstant(i) => '{my.IntConstant(${ Expr(i) })}
    case LongConstant(l) => '{my.LongConstant(${ Expr(l) })}
    case FloatConstant(f) => '{my.FloatConstant(${ Expr(f) })}
    case DoubleConstant(d) => '{my.DoubleConstant(${ Expr(d) })}
    case CharConstant(c) => '{my.CharConstant(${ Expr(c) })}
    case StringConstant(s) => '{my.StringConstant(${ Expr(s) })}
    case UnitConstant() => '{my.UnitConstant}
    case NullConstant() => '{my.NullConstant}
    case ClassOfConstant(tpe) => '{my.ClassOfConstant(${ mkType(tpe) })}

  def mkType(tpe: TypeRepr): Expr[my.Type] = tpe match
    case ConstantType(constant) => '{ my.ConstantType(${mkConstant(constant)}) }
    case TermRef(qualifier, name) => '{my.TermRef(${mkType(qualifier)}, ${Expr(name)})}
    case TypeRef(qualifier, name) => '{my.TypeRef(${mkType(qualifier)}, ${Expr(name)})}
    case SuperType(thisTpe, superTpe) => '{my.SuperType(${mkType(thisTpe)}, ${mkType(superTpe)})}
    case Refinement(parent, name, info) => '{my.Refinement(${mkType(parent)}, ${Expr(name)}, ${mkType(info)})}
    case AppliedType(tycon, args) => '{my.AppliedType(${mkType(tycon)}, ${Expr.ofList(args.map(mkType))})}
    case AnnotatedType(underlying, annot) => '{my.AnnotatedType(${mkType(underlying)}, ${mkTerm(annot)})}
    case AndType(left, right) => '{my.AndType(${mkType(left)}, ${mkType(right)})}
    case OrType(left, right) => '{my.OrType(${mkType(left)}, ${mkType(right)})}
    case MatchType(bound, scrutinee, cases) => '{my.MatchType(${mkType(bound)}, ${mkType(scrutinee)}, ${Expr.ofList(cases.map(mkType))})}
    case ByNameType(underlying) => '{my.ByNameType(${mkType(underlying)})}
    case ParamRef(binder, paramNum) => '{my.ParamRef(${mkType(binder)}, ${Expr(paramNum)})}
    case ThisType(tref) => '{my.ThisType(${mkType(tref)})}
    case RecursiveThis(binder) => '{my.RecursiveThis(${mkRecursiveType(binder)})}
    case MethodType(paramNames, paramTypes, resType) => '{my.MethodType(${Expr(paramNames)}, ${Expr.ofList(paramTypes.map(mkType))}, ${mkType(resType)})}
    case PolyType(paramNames, paramTypes, resType) => '{my.PolyType(${Expr(paramNames)}, ${Expr.ofList(paramTypes.map(mkTypeBounds))}, ${mkType(resType)})}
    case TypeLambda(paramNames, paramTypes, resType) => '{my.TypeLambda(${Expr(paramNames)}, ${Expr.ofList(paramTypes.map(mkTypeBounds))}, ${mkType(resType)})}
    case MatchCase(pattern, rhs) => '{my.MatchCase(${mkType(pattern)}, ${mkType(rhs)})}
    case TypeBounds(low, hi) => '{my.TypeBounds(${mkType(low)}, ${mkType(hi)})}
    case NoPrefix() => '{my.NoPrefix}

  def mkTerm(term: Term): Expr[my.Term] = term match
    case New(tpt) => '{my.New(${mkType(tpt.tpe)})}

  def mkRecursiveThis(recThis: RecursiveThis): Expr[my.RecursiveThis] = recThis match
    case RecursiveThis(binder) => '{my.RecursiveThis(${mkRecursiveType(binder)})}
  def mkRecursiveType(recTpe: RecursiveType): Expr[my.RecursiveType] =
    '{my.RecursiveType(${mkType(recTpe.underlying)}, ${mkRecursiveThis(recTpe.recThis)})}
  def mkTypeBounds(typeBounds: TypeBounds): Expr[my.TypeBounds] = typeBounds match
    case TypeBounds(lo, hi) => '{my.TypeBounds(${mkType(lo)}, ${mkType(hi)})}

  mkType(TypeRepr.of[T])
```

Usage:

```
def myFun[T: TypeTag](foo: T) = println(typeOf[T])

myFun(1)
//TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,scala)),Int)
myFun("a")
//TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,lang)),String)
myFun((_: Int).toString)
//AppliedType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,scala)),Function1),List(TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,<root>)),scala),Int), TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,lang)),String)))
myFun(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2))
//AppliedType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,immutable)),Map),List(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,lang)),String), TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,scala)),Int)))
```

Comment: Welp. That's certainly not similar functionality, if you have to recreate the entire type representation in your own code to use `Type` effectively. But thank you, Dmytro.

Comment: @ToddO'Bryan Well, "recreating the entire representation" sounds too loud. `my.Type` is just a thin wrapper over `quotes.reflect.Type`. As you can see all the pattern matchings are written almost automatically. So I guess they can even be generated with more macro work. (Maybe even `quotes.reflect.Type` could be exposed outside macros. I just didn't figure out how exactly because of implicit `Quotes` and path-dependent types. Recreating the hierarchy was easier. If we try to expose `quotes.reflect.Type` we should start with exposing `scala.quoted.Quotes`.

Comment: @ToddO'Bryan Its implementation `scala.quoted.runtime.impl.QuotesImpl` is a wrapper over `dotty.tools.dotc.core.Contexts.Context`, a compiler context. So it's actually not supposed to be exposed). We shouldn't confuse functionality and implementation details. In Scala 2 implicit `TypeTag` is generated by the compiler so this work is hidden but this is "implementation details". What functionality with `TypeTag` available in Scala 2 is now not available in Scala 3 with my self-made `TypeTag` for your use case?

Comment: Actually, the package @gaeljw provided seems to do the trick! :-)

Comment: Actually, the package Gaël J provide above sides the job.But thanks for the great example!

Comment: @ToddO'Bryan use with caution, it was more an opportunity for me to learn things. It might have many issues and there may be newer/simpler alternatives.

Comment: @GaëlJ Thanks for the warning, but I haven't found any of either -- issues or newer/simpler alternatives, yet.

Comment: This check only equality and equality isn't the biggest issue. Essentially, `izumi-reflect` does the same but stores more information and comes with a simplified typer simulator, that allows it to also check subtyping.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most comprehensive solution at the moment would be [izumi-reflect](https://github.com/zio/izumi-reflect)

Basically, it does a job similar to Dmytro's answer but it preserves lot more information so it can check both equality and subtyping.

It's completely portable and supports all Scala versions starting from 2.11 and all Scala target platforms (JVM, ScalaJS, Scala Native, GraalVM Native Image).

A very basic usage example wouldn't differ much from your snippet:

```scala
import izumi.reflect.Tag

trait Super
trait Sub extends Super

def myFun[T](foo: T)(implicit tag: Tag[T]) = {
  println(Tag[Sub].tag =:= tag.tag) // equality check
  println(Tag[Sub].tag <:< tag.tag) // subtype check
}

@main def hello() = {
  myFun(new Sub {})
}
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oMBd6z75QByUANxXdNppKw)

Comment: Is the Scala 3 version the same, just with `using` instead of `implicit`?

Comment: This _is_ a Scala 3 version written in a way which is compatible with Scala 2.